# Como manter uma conexão constante com o banco de dados para a atualização de dados sem a necessidade de refresh

Tags: php, mysql, servidor

Tenho uma aplicação que está trabalhando com banco de dados MySQL e PHP. Há dados nesse bd que são atualizados frequentemente por tratar-se de uma votação, porém essa votação ocorre num site externo e no meu site somente exibe o rank com o total de votos.

Para deixar esse rank mais dinâmico, eu queria manter uma conexão constante com o db para que o rank se atualize sempre que for contado um novo voto no banco de dados, sem a necessidade de um refresh.

```
$rank = $_POST["rank"] // Nesse caso usarei o rank de músicas.
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $rank ORDER BY votos LIMIT 0, 10");
```

> Um exemplo bem breve de como ocorre a exibição de dados.

Eu uso um echo pra retornar pro site o html que é gerado na própria página php e o jquery exibe.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso use a função **setTimeout** do javascript para chamar a requisição.

**Exemplo**

```js
// int t: difine o tempo que chamara a função novamente.
function atualizaRank(t) {
  $.get( "rank.php", function( data ) {
    $( "#resultado" ).html( data );
    setTimeout(function(){ atualizaRank(t) }, t);
  });
}

// 10000 milessegundo = 10 segundos
atualizaRank(10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```